# Json not converting to object in spring integration

Tags: java, json, spring-integration, amazon-sns

I'm having

```
.transform(Transformers.fromJson(SNSMessage.class))
```

not return a value transformed from my JSON. The JSON input is

```
{
    "Type": "Notification",
    "MessageId": "b5c64f3f-59e3-5fce-9ad6-1e98973c9537",
    "TopicArn": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:194477963434:local-hera-update",
    "Subject": "com.accuity.hera.model.HeraNotification",
    "Message": "{\"id\":\"65e60559-cab5-4027-88a2-46185fbd50b9\",\"resourceType\":\"listItem\",\"action\":\"I\",\"timeOfAction\":\"2017-05-30T19:48:46Z\",\"source\":\"gwl\"}",
    "Timestamp": "2017-05-30T19:48:47.593Z",
    "SignatureVersion": "1",
    "Signature": "Xz0qg0byLMA1fwIRbi7aWcEzhtcLBOmzyUluL1W5URu4WaiEO3G\/+hPSpsFXGxcSYNYRgpKhL9QAP2qLkuMlSEMqiEOHaSr88UaB8QRV2lUEjdBAWpuFYVBPdb+jpo6n3m89vVHoYfFWk8yBkc0zuoRl4OYcUXfTZiWWQkkrT8r9OzWU8LxQwgf0jgr1xEoqbl7uMHIp7nHp3cKstQ0mbK6yxMQ8faxfDm+IwH3k8BBH2\/CXmRg9WME6JK77jvagMUHNhUahWKIjm4iz+TCQCdnmHQR21hmgxlkhdrSxZ1FBbk6BjxfX7gorEwwfY1gYNoZCXxsN63+4vSiFMlOAAQ==",
    "SigningCertURL": "https:\/\/sns.us-east-1.amazonaws.com\/SimpleNotificationService-b95095beb82e8f6a046b3aafc7f4149a.pem",
    "UnsubscribeURL": "https:\/\/sns.us-east-1.amazonaws.com\/?Action=Unsubscribe&SubscriptionArn=arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:194477963434:local-hera-update:7de3da56-9e6c-43ca-9abc-d46fff379380"
}
```

and the class definition is:

```
public class SNSMessage {
    private String Type;
    private String MessageId;
    private String TopicArn;
    private String Subject;
    private String Message;
    private String Timestamp;
    private String SignatureVersion;
    private String Signature;
    private String SigningCertURL;
    private String UnsubscribeURL;
}
```

any ideas why the SNSMessage is coming back with all its fields set to null?

Comment: Can't you use jackson's ObjectMapper?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26257622/convert-a-json-to-an-array-of-objects-in-spring-integration?rq=1

Comment: Federico Piazza--jackson's ObjectMapper is the underlying implementation,

Comment: Ivan Pronin--there's no traceback happening and it's not a question of complicated structures as in the question you referenced.

Comment: @DonHosek, then can't you do `ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); mapper.readValue(json, SNSMessage .class);` ?

Comment: That's what happens under the hood. The problem is that for some reason it's not working with this data/class combination.

Comment: @DonHosek does your class have all getters and setters? Btw, I see you have CamelCase json attributes, maybe you need to use `@JsonProperty` on each property to indicate the explicit name

Comment: Yes, it has all the getters and setters... I think JsonProperty might be the magic here given the weird capitalization of the fields in the JSON.

Comment: @DonHosek, my suspicion is the json capitalization you have, it won't match the regular getter/setters, so you will have to use `@JsonProperty("Type") private String type;` (note I used lower case for `type` variable and camelcase for the jsonProperty. Let me know, if this works I can create the answer to mark this question as solved

Comment: Aha, yes, I needed to add @JsonProperty to each field for Jackson to correctly handle the capitalized field names.

Comment: Incidentally, keeping my fields named with the uppercase, just adding @JsonProperty (with no arguments) does the magic all on its own.

Comment: @DonHosek, good to know that JsonProperty detects the pojo property capitalization. Have just added the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have is that your json attributes are using a different capitalization than your pojo properties.

It means you have `Type` as json attribute and `type` detected for your getter.

You need to use `@JsonProperty` annotation like this:

```
@JsonProperty("Type") 
private String type;
...
// getters / setters for type
```

Btw, if you don't want to follow the java naming standard and have `Type` as well as the pojo property, then just add the `@JsonProperty` to the property with no args